# How to click the "clone or download" button on https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/ through robotframework?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, robotframework

I am trying to automate downloading a repo from github. I cant click the element of `clone or download` button.

Code trials:

```
open browser              https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/    chrome

Click Element             //a[contains(@class,'btn btn-sm btn-primary')]
```

HTML:

```
<summary class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
    Clone or download
    <span class="dropdown-caret"></span>
  </summary>
```

Comment: Hello Welcome to stackoverflow , as i check about you mentioned above is not an issue. i found you're clicking with wrong xpath. i suggest you to use any extension tool in chrome like : " Relative xpath  Helper" for inspect any elements. to solve your issue is just change your xpath to : //SUMMARY[@class='btn btn-sm btn-primary']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the element with text as **Clone or download** you can use the following solution:

```
open browser              https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/    chrome
Click Element             //summary[@class='btn btn-sm btn-primary']
```

Comment: Thanks, Yeah it was misclick